# Where are Apache file access logs stored?

Tags: files, logs, syslog

Does anyone know where file access logs are stored, so I can run a `tail -f` command in order to see who is accessing a particular file.

I have XAMPP, which is an Apache server installed on my machine, which automatically logs the accesses. It is stored in my installation folder.

Comment: On what distribution, or with what hosting provider? Logs are typically under `/var/log`, but some systems have them elsewhere.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Ultimately, this depends on your Apache configuration. Look for `CustomLog` directives in your Apache configuration, see the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) for examples.

A typical location for all log files is `/var/log` and subdirectories. Try `/var/log/apache/access.log` or `/var/log/apache2/access.log` or `/var/log/httpd/access.log`. If the logs aren't there, try running `locate access.log access_log`.

Answer (score 47):

If you can't find the log with [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39008/40421), there are a couple more things you can try.

- Look in `/var/log/httpd`.
- Run `sudo locate access.log` as well as `sudo locate access_log`. The logs on my system were not visible except to root, and the file was called `access_log` instead of `access.log`.

Answer (score 33):

Apache server records all incoming requests and all requests processed to a log file. The format of the access log is highly configurable. The location and content of the access log are controlled by the CustomLog directive. Default apache access log file location:

RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora Linux Apache access file location –

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
```

Debian / Ubuntu Linux Apache access log file location –

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
```

FreeBSD Apache access log file location –

```
 /var/log/httpd-access.log
```

To find exact apache log file location, you can use grep command:

```
# grep CustomLog /usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf
# grep CustomLog /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# grep CustomLog /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Sample output:

```
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#CustomLog "/var/log/httpd-access.log" common
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd-access.log" combined
```

Comment: The best answer in my opinion: detailed, concise and multi-platform for most *nix.

Comment: This whole answer was copied from this page: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

Comment: Just remember to search also in defined virtual servers, i.e., on Ubuntu, their individual config files are in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

Answer (score 9):

**find Apache access.log file location on Debian / Ubuntu Linux**

On my machine `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` pointed to `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` environment variable instead of the log directory itself.

The following (additional) step has been required to find the actual log directory:

```
$ grep APACHE_LOG_DIR /etc/apache2/envvars
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
$
```

`envvars` contains default environment variables for Apache.

Thus, to view the access log, use

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```